# How to show/hide items of the list in Django? (using JS or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm writing website using Django framework, but i am newbie in this web-framework, and i don't know how to work with JavaScript in Django templates. I just wanted to show/hide items of the list onclick, but i show/hide only first or last item.

**My code:**

```
{% for mysong in album.song_set.all %}

<li onclick=action()><a>CLICK ME</a></li>

<div id="{{mysong.id}}">
    <h1>{{mysong}}</h1>
    <img src="{{album.album_logo}}" width="300px"><br/>
    <h2>Song: {{mysong.song_title}}</h2>

    <h2>Artist: {{album.artist}}</h2>
    <h2>
    <audio controls>
            <source src="{{mysong.audiotrack.url}}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    </h2>
</div>
<script>
    function action() {

      var added_item_button = document.getElementById('{{mysong.id}}');
      var actualDisplay = getComputedStyle(added_item_button).display;
      if (actualDisplay == 'none') {
        added_item_button.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        added_item_button.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

That's how i tried to show/hide items of the list that i iterated over. But it seems, that's doesn't work like that. Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why you are creating same javascript function for every song item? You can pass a parameter of div id in your javascript function and based on that you can select specific div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you end up with a bunch of slightly different JS functions, all declared as `function action() {...}`. In JS you can't have more than one value assigned to the same variable - so `action` only refers to one of these (the last to be declared, I believe), and the way you have set this code up means that any click will only show/hide that one item.

There are a number of better ways to do this which avoid this problem and will work correctly. One is to have just one function but pass a parameter to it.

This way, you will have just one JS function (declared completely outside your template loop), which looks like:

```
function action(id) {
  var added_item_button = document.getElementById(id);
  var actualDisplay = getComputedStyle(added_item_button).display;
  if (actualDisplay == 'none') {
    added_item_button.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    added_item_button.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

And have the `onclick` attribute of each `<li>` be as follows:

```
<li onclick="action({{ mysong.id }})"><a>CLICK ME</a></li>
```

There are alternatives though - including including an attribute on the `<li>` called, say, `data-id` which points to the ID of the element it needs to show and hide - which you can then fetch from within the `action` function.

I would also strongly encourage you not to include JS in your HTML via `onclick` attributes, but instead add such event handlers in your JS, such as via the `addEventListener` method.